# ¿Por qué cuando ejecuto este código de nuevo no me deja marcar algunas casillas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo este código, cuando lo ejecuto la primera vez funciona perfectamente, pero cuando lo ejecuto varias veces, es como si no me dejara clickar algunos espacios, no se si es algo del caché o si hay otro motivo y no tengo ni idea de como arreglarlo.

El programa funciona bien, pero como les digo cuando lo ejecuto otra vez, no funciona perfectamente.

```js
let palabras = [
    "caballos", "iguales", "caminante", "queso"
];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Juego del ahorcado</title>
    <style>
        .letras {position:absolute;left: 0px; top: 0px; border: 2px; border-style: double; margin: 5px; padding:5px; color: #F00; background-color: #0fc; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
        }
        .blancos { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; border:none; margin: 5px; padding: 5px; color: #006; background-color: white; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;text-decoration: underline; color: black; font-size: 24 px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="palabras.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        let ctx;
        let construirelemento; 
        let alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
        let alfabetoy = 300;
        let alfabetox = 20;
        let alfabetoancho = 25;
        let secreto;
        let letrasacertadas = 0;
        let secretox = 160;
        let secretoy =50;
        let secretoancho = 50;
        let colorhorca = "brown";
        let colorcara ="tan";
        let colorcuerpo ="tan";
        let colornudo ="#F60";
        let centrocuerpox = 70;
        let pasos = [
            dibujarsoga,
            dibujarcabeza,
            dibujarcuerpo,
            dibujarbrazoderecho,
            dibujarbrazoizquierdo,
            dibujarpiernaderecha,
            dibujarpiernaizquierda,
            dibujarlazo
        ];
        let actual = 0;
        function dibujarsoga (){
            ctx.lineWidth = 8;
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorhorca;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo (2,180);
            ctx.lineTo (40,180);
            ctx.moveTo (20,180);
            ctx.lineTo(20,40);
            ctx.moveTo (2,40);
            ctx.lineTo (80,40);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

        }
        function dibujarcabeza (){
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorcara;
            ctx.save(); //before scaling of circle to be oval
            ctx.scale (.6,1);
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx. arc (centrocuerpox /.6,80,10,0,Math.PI*2, false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();
        }

        function dibujarcuerpo (){
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorcuerpo;
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 90);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox, 125);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        function dibujarbrazoderecho (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 100);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox+20, 110);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        function dibujarbrazoizquierdo (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 100);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox-20, 110);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

            function dibujarpiernaderecha (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 125);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox+10, 155);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();


        }

        function dibujarpiernaizquierda (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 125);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox-10, 155);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

        }      
        function dibujarlazo (){
            ctx.strokeStyle =colornudo;
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox-10, 40);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox-5, 95);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.save();
            ctx.scale (1,.3);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc (centrocuerpox, 95/.3,8,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();
            dibujarcuello();
            dibujarcabeza();


        }
        function dibujarcuello () {
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorcuerpo;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 90);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox, 95);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

        }
        function init () {
            ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext ('2d');
            configurarjuego ();
            ctx.font ="bold 20pt Ariel";
        }

        function configurarjuego (){
            let i;
            let x;
            let y;
            let idunica;
            let an = alfabeto.length;
            for (i=0; i<an; i++) {

                idunica = "a"+String(i);
                d = document.createElement('alfabeto');
                d.innerHTML = (
                    "<div class = 'letras' id = '"+idunica+"'>"+alfabeto[i]+"</div>");
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                    x =alfabetox + alfabetoancho*i;
                    y = alfabetoy;
                    construirelemento.style.top = String(y)+"px";
                    construirelemento.style.left = String(x)+"px";
                    construirelemento.addEventListener ('click', elementoelegido, false);
            }
            let elec = Math.floor (Math.random() * palabras.length);
            secreto = palabras[elec];
            for (i=0; i<secreto.length;i++){
                idunica = "s"+String(i);
                d = document.createElement('secreto');
                d.innerHTML = (
                    "<div class ='blancos' id = '"+idunica+"'> __ </div>");
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                    x= secretox + secretoancho*i;
                    y = secretoy;
                    construirelemento.style.top = String(y)+"px";
                    construirelemento.style.left = String(x)+"px";
            }

            pasos [actual]();
            actual++;
            return false;
        }

        function elementoelegido(ev) {
            let not = true;
            let elegido = this.textContent;
            let i;
            let j;
            let idunica;
            let construirelemento;
            let out;
            for (i=0; i<secreto.length; i++)
            {
                if (elegido ==secreto[i]){
                    id ="s"+String(i);
                    document.getElementById(id).textContent = elegido;
                    not = false;
                    letrasacertadas++;
                    if (letrasacertadas ==secreto.length)
                    {
                        ctx.fillStyle = colorhorca;
                        out ="¡Has ganado!";
                        ctx.fillText (out,200,80);
                        ctx.fillText ("Recarga la página para jugar de nuevo.", 200,120);
                        for (j=0; j<alfabeto.length;j++){
                            idunica = "a"+String(j);
                            construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                            construirelemento.removeEventListener('click', elementoelegido, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (not) {
                pasos[actual]();
                actual++;
                if (actual>=pasos.length)
                {
                    for (i=0;i <secreto.length; i++){
                        id = "s"+String(i);
                        document.getElementById(id).textContent = secreto[i];
                    }
                    ctx.fillStyle = colorhorca;
                    out = "¡Has perdido!";
                    ctx.fillText (out, 200,80);
                    ctx.fillText ("Recarga la página para jugar de nuevo.", 200,120);
                    for (j=0; j<alfabeto.length; j++){
                        idunica = "a"+String(j);
                        construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                        construirelemento.removeEventListener('click', elementoelegido, false);
                    }
                }
            }
            let id = this.id;
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
        }
    

        
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init ();">
    <h1>Colgado</h1></br>
    <p>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="400">
            Tu navegador no soporta el elemento canvas de HTML5.
        </canvas>
    </br>
    </p>
    
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Revisa la consola cuando no te deja clickar los espacios para ver si hay algun error.

Comment: @alanfcm acabo de chequear y me dice "Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.elementoelegido (colgado.html:195)" ¿qué quiere decir?

Comment: El ID esta repetido o no lo declaraste, checa eso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
id ="s"+String(i);
```

La variable `id` no esta definida.  Necesitas declarar la variable asi:

```
let id ="s"+String(i);
```

Quedaria asi:

```js
let palabras = [
    "caballos", "iguales", "caminante", "queso"
];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Juego del ahorcado</title>
    <style>
        .letras {position:absolute;left: 0px; top: 0px; border: 2px; border-style: double; margin: 5px; padding:5px; color: #F00; background-color: #0fc; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
        }
        .blancos { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; border:none; margin: 5px; padding: 5px; color: #006; background-color: white; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;text-decoration: underline; color: black; font-size: 24 px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="palabras.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        let ctx;
        let construirelemento; 
        let alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
        let alfabetoy = 300;
        let alfabetox = 20;
        let alfabetoancho = 25;
        let secreto;
        let letrasacertadas = 0;
        let secretox = 160;
        let secretoy =50;
        let secretoancho = 50;
        let colorhorca = "brown";
        let colorcara ="tan";
        let colorcuerpo ="tan";
        let colornudo ="#F60";
        let centrocuerpox = 70;
        let pasos = [
            dibujarsoga,
            dibujarcabeza,
            dibujarcuerpo,
            dibujarbrazoderecho,
            dibujarbrazoizquierdo,
            dibujarpiernaderecha,
            dibujarpiernaizquierda,
            dibujarlazo
        ];
        let actual = 0;
        function dibujarsoga (){
            ctx.lineWidth = 8;
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorhorca;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo (2,180);
            ctx.lineTo (40,180);
            ctx.moveTo (20,180);
            ctx.lineTo(20,40);
            ctx.moveTo (2,40);
            ctx.lineTo (80,40);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

        }
        function dibujarcabeza (){
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorcara;
            ctx.save(); //before scaling of circle to be oval
            ctx.scale (.6,1);
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx. arc (centrocuerpox /.6,80,10,0,Math.PI*2, false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();
        }

        function dibujarcuerpo (){
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorcuerpo;
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 90);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox, 125);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        function dibujarbrazoderecho (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 100);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox+20, 110);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        function dibujarbrazoizquierdo (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 100);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox-20, 110);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

            function dibujarpiernaderecha (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 125);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox+10, 155);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();


        }

        function dibujarpiernaizquierda (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 125);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox-10, 155);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

        }      
        function dibujarlazo (){
            ctx.strokeStyle =colornudo;
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox-10, 40);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox-5, 95);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.save();
            ctx.scale (1,.3);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc (centrocuerpox, 95/.3,8,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();
            dibujarcuello();
            dibujarcabeza();


        }
        function dibujarcuello () {
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorcuerpo;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 90);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox, 95);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

        }
        function init () {
            ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext ('2d');
            configurarjuego ();
            ctx.font ="bold 20pt Ariel";
        }

        function configurarjuego (){
            let i;
            let x;
            let y;
            let idunica;
            let an = alfabeto.length;
            for (i=0; i<an; i++) {

                idunica = "a"+String(i);
                d = document.createElement('alfabeto');
                d.innerHTML = (
                    "<div class = 'letras' id = '"+idunica+"'>"+alfabeto[i]+"</div>");
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                    x =alfabetox + alfabetoancho*i;
                    y = alfabetoy;
                    construirelemento.style.top = String(y)+"px";
                    construirelemento.style.left = String(x)+"px";
                    construirelemento.addEventListener ('click', elementoelegido, false);
            }
            let elec = Math.floor (Math.random() * palabras.length);
            secreto = palabras[elec];
            for (i=0; i<secreto.length;i++){
                idunica = "s"+String(i);
                d = document.createElement('secreto');
                d.innerHTML = (
                    "<div class ='blancos' id = '"+idunica+"'> __ </div>");
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                    x= secretox + secretoancho*i;
                    y = secretoy;
                    construirelemento.style.top = String(y)+"px";
                    construirelemento.style.left = String(x)+"px";
            }

            pasos [actual]();
            actual++;
            return false;
        }

        function elementoelegido(ev) {
            let not = true;
            let elegido = this.textContent;
            let i;
            let j;
            let idunica;
            let construirelemento;
            let out;
            for (i=0; i<secreto.length; i++)
            {
                if (elegido ==secreto[i]){
                    let id ="s"+String(i);
                    document.getElementById(id).textContent = elegido;
                    not = false;
                    letrasacertadas++;
                    if (letrasacertadas ==secreto.length)
                    {
                        ctx.fillStyle = colorhorca;
                        out ="¡Has ganado!";
                        ctx.fillText (out,200,80);
                        ctx.fillText ("Recarga la página para jugar de nuevo.", 200,120);
                        for (j=0; j<alfabeto.length;j++){
                            idunica = "a"+String(j);
                            construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                            construirelemento.removeEventListener('click', elementoelegido, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (not) {
                pasos[actual]();
                actual++;
                if (actual>=pasos.length)
                {
                    for (i=0;i <secreto.length; i++){
                        id = "s"+String(i);
                        document.getElementById(id).textContent = secreto[i];
                    }
                    ctx.fillStyle = colorhorca;
                    out = "¡Has perdido!";
                    ctx.fillText (out, 200,80);
                    ctx.fillText ("Recarga la página para jugar de nuevo.", 200,120);
                    for (j=0; j<alfabeto.length; j++){
                        idunica = "a"+String(j);
                        construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                        construirelemento.removeEventListener('click', elementoelegido, false);
                    }
                }
            }
            let id = this.id;
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
        }
    

        
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init ();">
    <h1>Colgado</h1></br>
    <p>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="400">
            Tu navegador no soporta el elemento canvas de HTML5.
        </canvas>
    </br>
    </p>
    
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: listo amigo, ahora si funciona correctamente, con razón no me funcionaba!!

Answer (score 6):

tu error es el ambito de las variables utilizas `id` mas de 1 vez pero haces referencia a la mas global ya que en ambitos mas bajos no utlizas `let` por lo que buscara fuera del scope si esta esta declarada y tomara  el valor de la misma y no la definida en sus propio escope! quedaria asi

```
let id ="s"+String(i);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Juego del ahorcado</title>
    <style>
        .letras {position:absolute;left: 0px; top: 0px; border: 2px; border-style: double; margin: 5px; padding:5px; color: #F00; background-color: #0fc; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
        }
        .blancos { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; border:none; margin: 5px; padding: 5px; color: #006; background-color: white; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;text-decoration: underline; color: black; font-size: 24 px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let palabras = [
            "caballos", "iguales", "caminante", "queso"
        ];
        let ctx;
        let construirelemento; 
        let alfabeto = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
        let alfabetoy = 300;
        let alfabetox = 20;
        let alfabetoancho = 25;
        let secreto;
        let letrasacertadas = 0;
        let secretox = 160;
        let secretoy =50;
        let secretoancho = 50;
        let colorhorca = "brown";
        let colorcara ="tan";
        let colorcuerpo ="tan";
        let colornudo ="#F60";
        let centrocuerpox = 70;
        let pasos = [
            dibujarsoga,
            dibujarcabeza,
            dibujarcuerpo,
            dibujarbrazoderecho,
            dibujarbrazoizquierdo,
            dibujarpiernaderecha,
            dibujarpiernaizquierda,
            dibujarlazo
        ];
        let actual = 0;
        function dibujarsoga (){
            ctx.lineWidth = 8;
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorhorca;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo (2,180);
            ctx.lineTo (40,180);
            ctx.moveTo (20,180);
            ctx.lineTo(20,40);
            ctx.moveTo (2,40);
            ctx.lineTo (80,40);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

        }
        function dibujarcabeza (){
            ctx.lineWidth = 3;
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorcara;
            ctx.save(); //before scaling of circle to be oval
            ctx.scale (.6,1);
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx. arc (centrocuerpox /.6,80,10,0,Math.PI*2, false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();
        }

        function dibujarcuerpo (){
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorcuerpo;
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 90);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox, 125);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        function dibujarbrazoderecho (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 100);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox+20, 110);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        function dibujarbrazoizquierdo (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 100);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox-20, 110);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

            function dibujarpiernaderecha (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 125);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox+10, 155);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();


        }

        function dibujarpiernaizquierda (){
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 125);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox-10, 155);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

        }      
        function dibujarlazo (){
            ctx.strokeStyle =colornudo;
            ctx.beginPath ();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox-10, 40);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox-5, 95);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.save();
            ctx.scale (1,.3);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc (centrocuerpox, 95/.3,8,0,Math.PI*2,false);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();
            dibujarcuello();
            dibujarcabeza();


        }
        function dibujarcuello () {
            ctx.strokeStyle = colorcuerpo;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo (centrocuerpox, 90);
            ctx.lineTo (centrocuerpox, 95);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();

        }
        function init () {
            ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext ('2d');
            configurarjuego ();
            ctx.font ="bold 20pt Ariel";
        }

        function configurarjuego (){
            let i;
            let x;
            let y;
            let idunica;
            let an = alfabeto.length;
            for (i=0; i<an; i++) {

                idunica = "a"+String(i);
                d = document.createElement('alfabeto');
                d.innerHTML = (
                    "<div class = 'letras' id = '"+idunica+"'>"+alfabeto[i]+"</div>");
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                    x =alfabetox + alfabetoancho*i;
                    y = alfabetoy;
                    construirelemento.style.top = String(y)+"px";
                    construirelemento.style.left = String(x)+"px";
                    construirelemento.addEventListener ('click', elementoelegido, false);
            }
            let elec = Math.floor (Math.random() * palabras.length);
            secreto = palabras[elec];
            for (i=0; i<secreto.length;i++){
                idunica = "s"+String(i);
                d = document.createElement('secreto');
                d.innerHTML = (
                    "<div class ='blancos' id = '"+idunica+"'> __ </div>");
                    document.body.appendChild(d);
                    construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                    x= secretox + secretoancho*i;
                    y = secretoy;
                    construirelemento.style.top = String(y)+"px";
                    construirelemento.style.left = String(x)+"px";
            }

            pasos [actual]();
            actual++;
            return false;
        }

        function elementoelegido(ev) {
            let not = true;
            let elegido = this.textContent;
            let i;
            let j;
            let idunica;
            let construirelemento;
            let out;
            for (i=0; i<secreto.length; i++)
            {
                if (elegido ==secreto[i]){
                    let id ="s"+String(i);
                    document.getElementById(id).textContent = elegido;
                    not = false;
                    letrasacertadas++;
                    if (letrasacertadas ==secreto.length)
                    {
                        ctx.fillStyle = colorhorca;
                        out ="¡Has ganado!";
                        ctx.fillText (out,200,80);
                        ctx.fillText ("Recarga la página para jugar de nuevo.", 200,120);
                        for (j=0; j<alfabeto.length;j++){
                            idunica = "a"+String(j);
                            construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                            construirelemento.removeEventListener('click', elementoelegido, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (not) {
                pasos[actual]();
                actual++;
                if (actual>=pasos.length)
                {
                    for (i=0;i <secreto.length; i++){

                        let id = "s"+String(i);
                        document.getElementById(id).textContent = secreto[i];
                    }
                    ctx.fillStyle = colorhorca;
                    out = "¡Has perdido!";
                    ctx.fillText (out, 200,80);
                    ctx.fillText ("Recarga la página para jugar de nuevo.", 200,120);
                    for (j=0; j<alfabeto.length; j++){
                        idunica = "a"+String(j);
                        construirelemento = document.getElementById(idunica);
                        construirelemento.removeEventListener('click', elementoelegido, false);
                    }
                }
            }
            let id = this.id;
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
        }
    

        
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init ();">
    <h1>Colgado</h1></br>
    <p>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="400">
            Tu navegador no soporta el elemento canvas de HTML5.
        </canvas>
    </br>
    </p>
    
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: ciertamente 2 ojos ven mejor que uno!